# Make global results header in a view appear below exposed filters

Tags: 7, views, theming

I need to make the text in a global results header appear below the exposed filters on a view and it doesn't give me an option to wrap the header separately from the exposed filters so I can move it below. How can this be done?

Answer (score 0):

You could create a custom block and execute php. Something like this:

```
$view = views_get_view('my_view');
// get global header
$view->execute();
$objects = $view->result;
```

Comment: no the header has the Global: Results summary, won't work out side the view.

Comment: I updated my answer to reflect this new information.

Comment: Hi , if I put a block in separately it will be all messed up when the screen becomes responsive I think.  Is there anyway to do it within the view ?

Comment: Dag (oeps ... hi!) Wim ... answers are for answers, questions to clarify questions belong in comments ... To avoid your answer gets converted to a comment (via moderation), you may want to remove the first parg from your "answer", ok? Groeten (from the other side of BXL)!

Comment: Dag Pierre ;) You're right, I updated my answer.

Comment: Merci for taking my advice ... About the actual answer now: personally I don't like PHP code in a (custom) block. Or more general: anything that makes PHP code getting stored in the drupal database (eg used in some Rules Conditions). But of course, that's a matter of preference ...